# Cannot delete Firebase user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

[image]When trying to delete a firebase user an error is thrown and it is unsuccessful.

I have tried Changing permissions, and making multiple user accounts.

```
  static Future deleteCurrectUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    if (user == null) {
        throw('No user');
    }else{

    user.delete().then((result) {
        print('User deleted');
        return true;
        }).catchError((e) {
        Sentry.report(e);
        return false;
        }).timeout(databaseTimeoutDuration,
            onTimeout: () => throw (TimeoutException(
                'Timedout trying to delete current user',
                databaseTimeoutDuration)));
    }
```

}

The error thrown is :

I/flutter (22331): PlatformException(USER_REQUIRED, Please authenticate with Firebase first, null)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because user token is expired. For some firebase operations like `delete` or `updateProfile` is needed reauth the user before. Below a single snipet to user reauth.

```
static Future<FirebaseUser> reauthCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser fbUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    // this object holds user email and password needed to make reauth.
    UserRepository repository = UserRepository.instance;
    AuthCredential credential;

    // assumuming that user auth using email & password
    credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(
        email: repository.userLogin,
        password: repository.userPassword);

    fbUser = await fbUser.reauthenticateWithCredential( credential )
        .catchError((error){ print("FirebaseAuthHelper::reauthCurrentUser $error"); });
    // force reloading...
    await fbUser.reload();
    return fbUser;
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You are supposed to prompt the user for signin credentials just to sign out user??

Comment: @ScottF check the official docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user